# Handling cancelled context in Go

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I'm looking to cleanly handle a context that could be cancelled in my program. I will model a skeleton of it.

```golang
ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
defer cancel()

// tracks errors or successes
completionChannel := make(chan bool)

go func1(ctx)
go func2(ctx)

numberOfFunctions := 2
for i := 0; i < numberOfFunctions; i++ {
 
 // async signal to know if channel was successful or not
 result <- completionChannel
 if !result {

   // should cancel all further processing of the go routines initialized above
   cancel()
   return
 }
}
```

- `completionChannel` is populated with a bool (false = failure, true = success)
- if value read off channel is false, cancel all running go routines

```golang
func func1(ctx) {
   retry := true
   while (retry) {

      // if context is cancelled, then terminate early (how do I do this elegantly?)

      err := doThing()
      if err.Status == 404 {
        retry = false
      }
   }
}
```

Imagine `func1` and `func2` are almost identical. They do a thing over and over (think exponential backoff). I want to prevent iterations from continuing if the context was cancelled to prevent memory leaks. Because reading off a channel that isn't cancelled is blocking, how do I add this where the comment lives?

### Edit:

Can I just add a non-blocking select?

```golang
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            fmt.Println("returning!")
            return
        default:
        }
```

Comment: Use [errgroup.WithContext](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sync/errgroup#WithContext).

Comment: wow, that's awesome! Didn't know this existed. Would the edit I posted above also be viable solution?

Answer (score 0):

check this out

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    defer cancel()

    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(2)
    go func1(ctx, cancel, &wg)
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
    go func1(ctx, cancel, &wg)

    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("All goroutines are closed")
}

func func1(ctx context.Context, cancel context.CancelFunc, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        fmt.Println("Goroutine closed by context cancel status")
        wg.Done()
        return
    default:
        status := doThing()
        if status == 404 {
            fmt.Println("Goroutine closed by 404 status")
            cancel()
            wg.Done()
            return
        }
    }
}

func doThing() int {
    return 404
}
```

Here i modified `doThing` func to test it when status failed

Also i've used `sync.WaitGroup` to wait for all others goroutines ending

To close all other goroutines you also need to provide `cancel` func to all of them

In case you need to track statuses you can simply create `completionChannel` push all the statuses there (be careful with chan length (it's going to be length == routines count)). Or use slice to push info there and read it after all goroutines are quit. **Don't read from it in process of appending info - in can cause race condition** i suppose